# How can I keep CSS 3D Cube vertex inside container

Tags: html, css, 3d, instagram, css-transforms

I am trying to replicate Instagram Stories 3D transition effect.

To see the transition view a user story and slide from left to right to go to another user story.

On Instagram the vertexes are always visible on the screen but while trying to replicate this with CSS, during the rotation the top and bottom vertexes go outside of the container as on this image bellow:

[image]

How can I make the rotation keeping the vertexes inside the visible area, same way Instagram does during their transitions.

Here is the exercise code:

```css
.history-wrapper {
 display:block;
}

.rotate-previous {
 transform:rotateY(90deg) translateX(50%) translateZ(0);
}

.rotate-next {
 transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateX(-190px) translateZ(190px);
}

.history-container {
 display:inline-flex;
 height: 100%;
 left:0;
 min-width:100%;
 position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transition: transform 1s;
 top:0;
 perspective-origin: 50% 100%;
}

.us-item {
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:0;
}

.us-item.left {
 transform:rotateY(-90deg);
 right:100%;
 transform-origin:right top; 
 z-index:1;
 background:cyan;
}
.us-item.center {
 transform:rotateY(0deg);
 z-index:2;
 background:green;
}

.us-item.right {
 left:100%;
 transform:rotateY(90deg);
 transform-origin:top left; 
 z-index:3;
 background:blue;
}

/* DEMO SPECIFIC CSS */
.history-wrapper {
 height:500px;
 margin:0 auto;
 perspective:380px;
 width:380px;
}

.us-item {
 background-color:#efefef;
 width:380px;
 height:500px;
}

.history-container {
 height:500px;
}

.history-container:hover {
 transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateX(-190px) translateZ(190px);
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 0px;">
     <div>
         <div class="os-stories history-wrapper">
             <div class="history-container">
                 <div>
                     <div class="us-item left">
                         <div class="us-item-content">
                             User Story Item Info
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div>
                     <div class="us-item center current">
                         <div class="us-item-content">
                             User Story Item Info
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div>
                     <div class="us-item right">
                         <div class="us-item-content">
                             User Story Item Info
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: play with transform-origin

Comment: put it in a container with a bunch of padding? [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6boz4c1/2/)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've been trying to change the transform origin, as it is on the example above is the best setting I've found. But maybe If there is a way of achieving what I am looking for, than I'm not finding it using only transform-origin.

Comment: @zgood I've thought of that but does not solve the issue. I have to keep the size. The idea is that the vertex points are never bigger than the height of the container.

Comment: yes i was playing with it and not easy, but am pretty conviced that we can have it by adjusting transform-origin ;)

Comment: Do you know how create the stories transition effect for instagram web app (not ios app)?The transition effect for web app is different then ios app.